# Forcing string representation of an array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to maintain the order of an array with mixed key types. The array contains mostly keys represented by string values -- but if you enter a numbered key it goes to the front. How can I force a key which is a number to be a string type?

E.g.

```
array = [];
array["one"] = "some data";
array["two"] = "some more data";
array["3"] = "this should not be the first element";
```

How can I make "3" a string type to prevent it from moving to the top of the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh wow did you ever open multiple cans of worms.

Javascript arrays are a special type of Javascript objects, and like all Javascript objects they can have arbitrary string properties:

```
const foo = [];
foo["bar"] = "hi";
```

However that string is a property of the array object, not an item in the array:

```
foo.forEach(console.log); // logs nothing
```

You can still access it like any other object property:

```
console.log(foo["bar"]); // "hi"
```

But it won't show up in the usual iterative constructs like c-style for loops or the map/forEach array methods.

The line in your example

```
array["3"] = "this should not be the first element";
```

is very different however, because of Javascript's playing fast and loose with type conversions this actually sets the string to the 4th slot in the array:

```
const bar = [];
bar["3"] = "oops!"; // equivalent to bar[3] = "oops!"
console.log(bar); // [empty x 3, "oops!"]
```

This piece of it is actually a good thing (other than the implicit conversion part) rather than a problem: sometimes you need a sparse array and JS supports those. Iterating it will only produce the one element:

```
bar.forEach((item, index) => console.log(item, index)); // ["oops", 3]
```

Note though that the string has the correct index of 3, and can be accessed that way even though there's nothing "in front" of it:

```
bar[3]; // "oops"
```

So the first two assignments in your example create properties on the array object, and the third assignment is the only one that actually adds an item to the array, at the 4th index (there's nothing at the first 3).

What you seem to want as Reese Casey suggests, is a plain object:

```
const foo = {}; // curly
foo["some string"] = "whatever";
```

However now the properties are basically unordered. If you want them to be in a guaranteed specific order you *do* want an array, but all your indicies will need to be integers, and should be sequential. You can achieve this easily by using the `.push` method:

```
foo = [];
foo.push("something");
foo.push("something else");
```

Now foo will have two elements, in the correct order, and index 0 and 1 respectively.

### Update based on comment on the other answer:

> I want some of the data to be ordered, and the rest of the data to follow

This can be accomplished through object destructuring:

```
const responseFromDB = {
  oneKeyICareAbout: 3,
  anotherKeyICareAbout: 2,
  foo: 6,
  bar: 7,
};

const {
  oneKeyICareAbout,
  anotherKeyICareAbout,
  *rest,
} = responseFromDB;

const stuffToDisplay = [
  oneKeyICareAbout,
  anotherKeyICareAbout,
  ...Object.values(rest),
]; // [3, 2, 6, 7]
```

And at least the destructured stuff you put in the array will be ordered because by doing so you've ordered it.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript arrays cannot have string indexes. This is actually working incorrectly as the index is adding a property to the array object.

Changing to an object makes more sense for this.

EDIT: Whilst below its mentioned you can have string indexes you are not actually using the array by doing so. The answer by Jared Smith goes into much more detail as to why.

Comment: Arrays are objects, and like all non-null objects they very much can have arbitrary string properties. Try it yourself in your browser console: `foo = []; foo["three"] = 3; console.log(foo["three"]); console.log(typeof foo);`. But you are essentially correct: one should pretty much *never* set a string property on an array.

Comment: they can have string indexes

Comment: By using a string index you are adding to the array object not an item in the array

Comment: My original solution to a problem was to use objects -- but in "older browsers" (ie. IE) they don't guarantee key:value order by insertion.

Comment: Can you not use a set or an array of objects?

E.g. `[{ id: "three", value: "the value" }, { id: "3", value: "the value" }]`

Comment: My actual use case is that I receive an object that is stored in a NoSQL database. When I output the data from the object to the webpage I want some of the data to be ordered, and the rest of the data to follow -- also, I don't want to be committed to specific keys (ie. I don't want to have to come back and hardcode keys later if new key:value pairs are introduced). My solution was to treat it as an object, and use Object.assign() to order it... but I was told that I cannot rely on order in objects. So I looked at arrays. My solution was faulty, buy my quesiton was good (for my learning!)

Comment: @JeffVdovjak I've updated my answer based on this exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain what is happening with your array-object mixture. For having an indexable thing which can reproduce the original order, you can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The `Map` object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys.

```js
array = new Map();
array.set("one","some data");
array.set("two","some more data");
array.set("3","this should not be the first element");

console.log("Test of get:",array.get("two"));
console.log("Test of order:");
for(let entry of array)
  console.log(entry);
```